# How to change date format to 'YYYY/DD/MM'?

Tags: sql, oracle

i got financial year 1st month April and 1st week date using (:weekno) from this query

```
select TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS((Select ((TRUNC (Trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')+( :weekno)*7,'IW'))+1) fdt from duaL),+3))
  from dual
```

Output got:03-APR-17
but i want output this format 'YYYY/DD/MM' 04/03/2017

Comment: What form is the original data in? Is it a `DATE` or `DATETIME` field?

Comment: Also: Please, pick **one** of MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: how about this `SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()))+  '/'+  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 103)`

Comment: 'YYYY/DD/MM'  =  04/03/2017 ? is It Right ? or you want 2017/04/03

Comment: try using `CONVERT(char(10),GETDATE(),126)` in SQL Server

Comment: Why do you use 2 times `SELECT ... FROM dual`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need date value:

```
select to_date(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS((Select ((TRUNC (Trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')+( :weekno)*7,'IW'))+1) fdt from duaL),+3)),'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual
```

If need string value:

```
select TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS((Select ((TRUNC (Trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')+( :weekno)*7,'IW'))+1) fdt from duaL),+3),'yyyy/mm/dd')from dual
```

Comment: date value came This Format 4/17/0003

Comment: String query work perfect for ex: if i select weekno 1 means 1st date of week o/p 03/04/2017 but select weekno 5 means o/p came 30/04/2017 i need MAY month week 1st date 01/05/2017

Answer (score 1):

You are using dual twice. There is no need for that.

Use `to_char` with `yyyy/mm/dd` format to get `2017/03/04`:

```
select
    to_char(
        add_months(
            trunc(
                trunc(sysdate,'YY') + :week_no * 7, 'IW'
            ) + 1, 3
        ), 'yyyy/mm/dd'
    ) dt
from dual;
```

Use `to_char` with `dd/mm/yyyy` format to get `04/03/2017`:

```
select
    to_char(
        add_months(
            trunc(
                trunc(sysdate,'YY') + :week_no * 7, 'IW'
            ) + 1, 3
        ), 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    ) dt
from dual;
```